# Работа логических операторов and и or

Tags: python

Требуется проверить, является ли вводимая строка одной буквой или вводимая строка состоит из букв и ее длина совпадает с длинной  заранее загаданного слова.

```py
guessed_word = 'привет'

word_entered = input('Введи целиком слово или  одну букву \n').upper()  # Вводим предположительную букву или слово

while word_entered != word_entered.isalpha() and len(word_entered) != len(guessed_word) or word_entered != word_entered.isalpha() and len(word_entered) != 1:
     word_entered = input('Одну букву или слово целиком \n')
```

Eсли условие построить на проверку одной буквы, то все работает:

```py
while word_entered != word_entered.isalpha() and len(word_entered) != 1:
     word_entered = input('Одну букву или слово целиком \n')
```

Но, как только появляется оператор `or`, все ломается.

Отсюда возникает вопрос, почему оно перестает работать и почему?

Comment: Покажите пример кода, который не работает.

Comment: guessed_word = 'привет'

word_entered = input('Введи целиком слово или  одну букву \n').upper()  # Вводим предположительную букву или слово

while word_entered != word_entered.isalpha() and len(word_entered) != len(guessed_word) or word_entered != word_entered.isalpha() and len(word_entered) != 1:
     word_entered = input('Одну букву или слово целиком \n')

Comment: А что делает код? Какой результат требуете?

Comment: Это проверка на дурака, требуется чтобы пользователь ввел одну букву или слово длинной равной длинной заранее загаданному слову т.e == len(guessed_word)

Comment: @ИванТекин Вас не смущает, что в комментариях форматирования нет? Добавляйте уточнения в текст вопроса кнопкой "править".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы используете в одном логическом выражении и `and` и `or`, то во избежание неприятных сюрпризов используйте явно скобки для задания приоритетов.

Для справки: [Таблица приоритетов в Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Примеры работы логических операторов без явного задания приоритетов:

```
In [83]: True and False or True and True
Out[83]: True

In [84]: True and False or False and True
Out[84]: False
```

т.е. `True and False or False and True` интерпретируется как:

```
In [89]: (True and False) or (False and True)
Out[89]: False
```

PS не уверен, что вы именно это имели ввиду когда написали вашу проверку без скобок

---

> требуется чтобы пользователь ввел одну букву или слово длинной равной длинной заранее загаданному слову т.e `== len(guessed_word)`

```
while not (word_entered.isalpha() 
           and 
           (len(word_entered) == len(guessed_word) or len(word_entered) == 1)):
    word_entered = input('Одну букву или слово целиком \n')
```

Comment: Это именно то, что мне требовалось! Благодарю

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю может кому-то более понятное разъяснение. Согласно таблице приоритетов, приведённой в ответе у MaxU уважаемого, у `and` приоритет выше, чем у `or`, т.е. сначала выполняются все `and`, а уже после этого все `or`, т.е. например такое выражение:

```
a and b or c and d
```

Эквивалентно выражению:

```
(a and b) or (c and d)
```

И это легко запомнить, если знать, что:

- `and` называется **логическим умножением**
- `or` называется **логическим сложением**

А в каком порядке вычислять такое арифметическое выражение с умножениями и сложениями мы все прекрасно знаем:

```
a * b + c * d = (a * b) + (c * d)
```

Comment: все правильно. Что-то я перемудрил)